# DataGridView Binding from Multiple columns

Tags: c#

I have a confusion.. The confusion is this that i am having a datagridview on my windows form. I want to ask that, can a datagridview can be bind from multiple tables having same column Names?

One table has columns Quantity, Particular and Rate
Other table has also the same column Names as above. 
Can these two tables can be bind to a single datagridview?
My question is that is this possible?

Comment: Why the downvote? The question appears legitimate to me. +1

Answer (score 1):

When you query on two table that have a common column name, in join select must rename once(as), so return query certainly has column with different name:

```
Select tbl1.Quantity as quantity1 , tbl2.Quantity as quantity2,...
```

Otherwise if you query like this:

```
Select tbl1.Quantity , tbl2.Quantity,...
```

Sql optimizer rename one of the column and return data with like(maybe): [quantity],[expr1]

Comment: please elaborate a bit :)
your help will be greatly appreciated indeed.
thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from RedHat it's ok, if you restrict to a SQL provider. More generally, you can use Linq (the very same **select** operator!) to combine multiple datasource (i.e. tables, or iterators). Then simply assign it to the DataGridView.
**EDIT**: here a sample, HTH

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test_linq_join
{
    class MainClass
    {
        private class Cat
        {
            // Auto-implemented properties.
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        private class Dog
        {
            // Auto-implemented properties.
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            // these are simple datasources with overlapped fields (i.e. columns)
            Cat[] Cats = { new Cat { Age = 1, Name = "Leo" }, new Cat { Age = 3, Name = "Felix" } };
            Dog[] Dogs = { new Dog { Age = 10, Name = "Old"}, new Dog { Age = 1, Name = "New" } };

            var Pets =
                from C in Cats
                from D in Dogs
                    select new { AgeC = C.Age, AgeD = D.Age, NameC = C.Name, nameD = D.Name };

            var F = new Form();
            F.Controls.Add(new DataGridView { DataSource = Pets.ToList() });
            F.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me doing it with linq? actually i was so very enthusiastic by doing it with linq but i dont know a bit of it.. :/

Comment: The type 'CateringShop.CateringShopDataClassesDataContext' in 'D:\Projects\CateringShop\CateringShop\CateringShop\CateringShopDataClasses.designer.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'CateringShop.CateringShopDataClassesDataContext' in 'D:\Projects\CateringShop\CateringShop\CateringShop\bin\Debug\CateringShop.exe'. Using the type defined in'D:\Projects\CateringShop\CateringShop\CateringShop\CateringShopDataClasses.designer.cs'. D:\Projects\CateringShop\CateringShop\CateringShop\Bill.cs
when i implement linq to sql in my application, i receive warnings..

Answer (score 0):

Use AliasName in your query to descriminate the columns

```
  SELECT Table1.Quantity AS Quantity1,Table2.Quantity AS Quantity2
  FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.SomeID=Table2.OtherID
```

Then use Quantity1 and Quantity2 for binding different columns.

Comment: and what if i have dgv in my winform, and in that dgv i am having 3 columns named Quantity,Particular,Rate.
i want to have the data of these 3 columns from table1 to the dgv and also the data of table2 of the same columns in that same dgv columns

Comment: @AbidAli : Have this result in a datatable and you can bind the data table as the data source.